# how to write firebase rules for a specific platform

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

can I write a **firebase rule** for a specific platform? e.g. I want this node to be available for all IOS users only(Android can't read/write in it)?

Comment: This can be done using User roles. Please have a look here [Control Access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in information in the user profile about the platform(s) they're using. In fact, since a user can be connecting from different platforms, this information would have to be an array of platforms.

As ArbenMaloku commented, you could set a "this profile is associated with this platform" claim using the Firebase Admin SDK. But you'd have to determine what platform the user is on yourself there. The simplest way would be to have each client write the information into the database. Just be aware that this can be spoofed, so it won't be secure.